# Nusoap Missing "type" attribute

Tags: php, xml, nusoap

I have a nusoap response that seems to be working correctly however its not returning the attribute *"type"* as part of the returned array.

There is another attribute *"id"* that does come through however. I'm extremely new to Nusoap and SOAP in general and I can't seem to find any information on it.

Here is a snippet of what the XML looks like using a generic SOAP tester:

```
<image id="C404927" type="icon_image_off">
    <url>
        http://xml.catmms.com/servlet/ImageServlet?imageId=C404927
    </url>
</image>
```

Here is a snippet of the returned array

```
[2]=>
array(2) {
    ["url"]=>
        string(58) "http://xml.catmms.com/servlet/ImageServlet?imageId=C404927"
    ["!id"]=>
        string(7) "C404927"
}
```

PHP is 5.2.6, nusoap is 1.123 *(taken from top of `nusoap.php`)*

Comment: I don't know Nusoap well, however if you get back an array, it's probably that the *type* doesn't play any role and therefore is not part of the array. You might want to add the code how you do the SOAP request to have a bit more context in your question.